# yii2 checkbox not working its always submit 0 in POST

Tags: php, yii2, crud

I have a simple field `is_active` in form `tinyint` in db also defined as integer in rules when I submit form checkbox checked or unchecked it's always submitting 0.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'is_active')->checkbox();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this when dealing with my form's checkboxes:

`$model= (isset($_POST['is_active'])) ? 1 : 0;`

Also make sure you don't set a specific value for the checkbox. Otherwise you will get strange results.

Comment: This is not a yii way , coz yii also set a hidden field to hijack non checked checkbox values

Answer (score 0):

This patch worked for me, but I am still wondering why this issue has not been reported yet on yii2 platform or I am doing something wrong here

```
diff --git a/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseHtml.php b/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseHtml.php
index 66a5730..d2bd49c 100644
--- a/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseHtml.php
+++ b/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseHtml.php
@@ -706,10 +706,10 @@ class BaseHtml
      *
      * @return string the generated checkbox tag
      */
-    public static function checkbox($name, $checked = false, $options = [])
+    public static function checkbox($name, $value, $checked = false, $options = [])
     {
         $options['checked'] = (bool) $checked;
-        $value = array_key_exists('value', $options) ? $options['value'] : '1';
+        //$value = array_key_exists('value', $options) ? $options['value'] : '1';
         if (isset($options['uncheck'])) {
             // add a hidden field so that if the checkbox is not selected, it still submits a value
             $hidden = static::hiddenInput($name, $options['uncheck']);
@@ -892,7 +892,7 @@ class BaseHtml
             if ($formatter !== null) {
                 $lines[] = call_user_func($formatter, $index, $label, $name, $checked, $value);
             } else {
-                $lines[] = static::checkbox($name, $checked, array_merge($itemOptions, [
+                $lines[] = static::checkbox($name, $value, $checked, array_merge($itemOptions, [
                     'value' => $value,
                     'label' => $encode ? static::encode($label) : $label,
                 ]));
@@ -1446,7 +1446,7 @@ class BaseHtml
             $options['id'] = static::getInputId($model, $attribute);
         }

-        return static::checkbox($name, $checked, $options);
+        return static::checkbox($name, $value, $checked, $options);
     }

     /**
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the code isn't working as intended on your install, and I don't know why. I can't replicate the problem, but the problem does not appear to be with Yii itself, but with your specific site not obtaining the checkbox value correctly.  Your corrections are fixing a problem that is specific to you, so you might run into maintainability problems by manually patching the core, rather than fixing whatever is causing your site not to obtain the checkbox value correctly. If it really was a bug in the core it would be affecting everyone, but it isn't.

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong, but there is something. I will rollback this patch & will try to find out the root cause when get some time.